# Animation interface doubts

Tags: animation, keyframes, shortcut

I am an animator new to the blender and I have some queries.

1. Can any one tell me how to move keys in time slider?
2. How to change from real time speed to Play every frame like maya?
3. How to key directly without getting insert key frame popup menu while pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, like Maya shortcut <kbd>S</kbd>?

Comment: Please ask multiple questions separately. One question per post.